# jquery binding to select changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden select which should be automatically selected via a visible select, my jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var selected_val = $('#id_foo option:selected').val();
    $('#id_bar').val(selected_val);

    $("#id_foo").change(function() {
        selected_val = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#id_bar').val(selected_val);
    });

});
```

This works fine, but the page I am working on has the option to add a value to the (visible) select on the fly. How do I bind to this event and add this to the hidden list before updating the selected value?

Comment: Does the hidden element have to be a `select`? Of course that depends on what you need it for, but perhaps it could just be an `<input type="hidden">` element, in which case you wouldn't have to worry about populating the list of possible values.

Comment: I understand but the form and views are generated by the framework, I want to stay away from that

Answer (score 2):

The best way to tackle this is to update the hidden select with the new values when you update the visible one.

Or, as per my comment, you could populate the hidden `select` when the visible one is changed:

```
$("#id_foo").change(function() {
    selected_val = $(this).attr('value');

    //clear and re-populate all of hidden select here
    $('#id_bar').val(selected_val);
});
```

Comment: That's what I expected, the problem is this is done by a library that is part of the used framework. Can I somehow wrap this function without hacking into the source?

Comment: You could make it so that when you update the second one you clear it and re-populate it first with the current contents of the visible select?

Comment: There's no signal to update the second one if the 'change' to the first isn't detected by .change(). The only event that 'sees' the new option seems to be DOMSubtreeModified which is on deprecated status.

Comment: Surely anytime the first one is changed the `change` event would be raised, and if the first one doesnt change you are not bothered about updating the second one?

Comment: The appending event is not seen as a change, I logged to console nothing printed after adding an option, only when using the mouse to select the new (or any) option change is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
    var $bar = $('#id_bar');
    var $foo = $('#id_foo');

    $bar.val($foo.val());

    $foo.change(function () {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        if ($bar.find('[value="' + newValue + '"]').length === 0) {
            $bar.append($('<option/>').val(newValue));
        }
        $bar.val(newValue);
    });
});
```

Before setting the new value, checks if the value is an option. If it's not, add as an option.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet correctly identifies the event and succesfully copies the select options from foo to bar. However it does not seem to set `:selected` correctly on either `id_foo` or `id_bar` and using DOMSubtreeModified feels hackish

```
$('#id_foo').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    var high = 0;
    $('#id_foo').children().each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val() > high) {
                high = $(this).val();
            }
        }
    );
    $('#id_foo').val(high);
    var new_options = $('#id_foo').clone();
    $('#id_bar').html('');
    $('#id_bar').append(new_options.children());
});
```

So, for now the best I could come up with:

```
$('#id_foo').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    location.reload();
});
```